# Can't click to button using co-ordinates in latest 3.0 selenium and FF

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

Can't click to button using co-ordinates in latest 3.0 selenium and FF.

I'm specifying partial code which launches FF48 browser, opens login page and tries to click to Sign In button. Clicking to button using co-ordinates works fine in Chrome but fails in FF.

## Environment:

```
Browser - FF48 (may be present with previous FF as well)
Selenium - Latest 3.0 beta jar

Works fine in latest Chrome.
```

## Code:

```
// Launch browser
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
webDriver =  new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

// Open login page and click to Sign button
WebElement we = null;
we = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css=input.ZLoginButton[value='Sign In']"));

Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver());
Action action = builder.moveToElement(we, 5, 5).click(we).build();
action.perform();
```

## Issue:

we element returned fine but move to element fails in FF, same code works fine in Chrome. I don't think this issue particularly for FF48 and may be present in all FF but interesting thing, is this issue in latest selenium 3.0 jar as far as move element and co-ordinates is concerned?

Even it works fine directly using :

```
we.click();
```

But i need to click to element using co-ordinates because in my Ajax application, some element click works only with co-ordinatest something like:

```
Action action = builder.moveToElement(we, 5, 5).click(we).build();
action.perform();
```

Does anyone have a idea about the recent issue? I'm sure this was working fine before in FF and already works fine in chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue regarding action class not working with geckodriver. We need to wait for its fix. Issue logged in selenium -> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Oarpito, please accept the question and hopefully it would be fixed soon :)

Comment: Meanwhile please vote to: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292178. I have added respective comment for all the issues.

Answer (score 0):

After a week I disable marionette (java):

`capability.setCapability("marionette", false);`

It's repair **everything**. Don't ask me why.